# How to recode values in haven_labelled vectors in R

Tags: r, dplyr, recode, r-haven

I am working with data imported from SPSS using the `haven` package, imported using `read_sav()`.

The data exists in columns of class `haven_labelled`, which is somewhat similar to a factor in that it contains a value and a label but is different in other ways.

I want to recode the values in the data and associated label values.

Here is an example:

```
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
library(labelled)
library(tidyr)

x <- structure(list(q0015_0001 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, 3, 1, 2, NA, NA, 3, 4, 2, NA, 2, 2, 4, NA,
 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, NA, NA, 2), label = "Menu Options/Variety", format.spss = "F8.2", labels = 
c(`Very Dissatisfied` = 1, Dissatisfied = 2, Neutral = 3, Satisfied = 4, `Very Satisfied` = 5), 
class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), q0015_0002 = structure(c(4, 4, NA, 5, 3, 3, 
NA, NA, 3, 4, 2, NA, 5, 2, 4, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, 2), label = "Cleanliness", format.spss
 = "F8.2", labels = c(`Very Dissatisfied` = 1, Dissatisfied = 2, Neutral = 3, Satisfied = 4, `Very
 Satisfied` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), q0015_0003 = 
structure(c(2, 2, NA, 3, 1, 2, NA, NA, 3, 4, 3, NA, 4, 3, 4, NA, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1),
 label = "Taste and Quality of Food", format.spss = "F8.2", labels = c(`Very Dissatisfied` = 1, 
Dissatisfied = 2, Neutral = 3, Satisfied = 4, `Very Satisfied` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
label = "File created by user")

x

# A tibble: 25 x 3
#               q0015_0001          q0015_0002             q0015_0003
#                <dbl+lbl>           <dbl+lbl>              <dbl+lbl>
# 1  3 [Neutral]            4 [Satisfied]       2 [Dissatisfied]     
# 2  5 [Very Satisfied]     4 [Satisfied]       2 [Dissatisfied]     
# 3 NA                     NA                  NA                    
# 4  3 [Neutral]            5 [Very Satisfied]  3 [Neutral]          
# 5  1 [Very Dissatisfied]  3 [Neutral]         1 [Very Dissatisfied]
# 6  2 [Dissatisfied]       3 [Neutral]         2 [Dissatisfied]     
# 7 NA                     NA                  NA                    
# 8 NA                     NA                  NA                    
# 9  3 [Neutral]            3 [Neutral]         3 [Neutral]          
#10  4 [Satisfied]          4 [Satisfied]       4 [Satisfied]        
# ... with 15 more rows
```

To illustrate the column structure better

```
x$q0015_0001

#<labelled<double>[25]>: Menu Options/Variety
# [1]  3  5 NA  3  1  2 NA NA  3  4  2 NA  2  2  4 NA  4  3  3  3  3  2 NA NA  2
#
#Labels:
# value             label
#     1 Very Dissatisfied
#     2      Dissatisfied
#     3           Neutral
#     4         Satisfied
#     5    Very Satisfied
```

The data include values from 1 to 5, each with a corresponding label (i.e., 1 = "Very Dissatisfied", etc.). `haven_labelled` allows numeric or character values.

I wish to change the values from `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` to `c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)` but preserve the labels in the same order (i.e., -2 = "Very Dissatisfied", etc.).

| Label | Old Value | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Very Dissatisfied | 1 | -2 |
| Dissatisfied | 2 | -1 |
| Neutral | 3 | 0 |
| Satisfied | 4 | 1 |
| Very Satisfied | 5 | 2 |

The closest I have come is using `dplyr::recode()`.  The `labelled` package is supposed to extend the `dplyr::recode()` method to work with labelled vectors [[1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/labelled/versions/2.9.1/topics/recode.haven_labelled)], but I haven't noticed a difference with/without it being loaded.

```
dplyr::recode(x$q0015_0001,`1` = -2, `2` = -1, `3` = 0, `4` = 1, `5` = 2)

#<labelled<double>[25]>: Menu Options/Variety
# [1]  0  2 NA  0 -2 -1 NA NA  0  1 -1 NA -1 -1  1 NA  1  0  0  0  0 -1 NA NA -1
#
#Labels:
# value             label
#     1 Very Dissatisfied
#     2      Dissatisfied
#     3           Neutral
#     4         Satisfied
#     5    Very Satisfied
```

Notice that the values in the data changed as expected (3 became 0, 5 became 2, etc.) but not the label values. This means that if you were to attempt to use `as_factor` (the labelled vector equivalent to `as.factor` from the `haven` package) to reference the labels instead of the values, the labels will be incorrect. The effect on the data is further illustrated when viewing the values and labels together.

```
x %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("q0015"), 
  ~recode(., `1` = -2, `2` = -1, `3` = 0, `4` = 1, `5` = 2)))

# A tibble: 25 x 3
#q0015_0001             q0015_0002             q0015_0003
#<dbl+lbl>              <dbl+lbl>              <dbl+lbl>
#1  0                      1 [Very Dissatisfied] -1                    
#2  2 [Dissatisfied]       1 [Very Dissatisfied] -1                    
#3 NA                     NA                     NA                    
#4  0                      2 [Dissatisfied]       0                    
#5 -2                      0                     -2                    
#6 -1                      0                     -1                    
#7 NA                     NA                     NA                    
#8 NA                     NA                     NA                    
#9  0                      0                      0                    
#10  1 [Very Dissatisfied]  1 [Very Dissatisfied]  1 [Very Dissatisfied]
# ... with 15 more rows
```

As shown, the labels still map to the old values.  In the recoded version, 1 and 2 are positive scores but still map to Very Dissatisfied/Dissatisfied, while -2, -1 and 0 are not recognized as labelled values.

**Question**
How may I recode labelled vectors such that the data values and label values are updated together and labels are preserved/mapped to the new values?

Comment: I'm okay with other functions than recode, though I prefer a solution that works in a dplyr pipeline with mutate(across()). The data set is based on multiple-choice/select-all style questions that have a column for each option. Variable names are q[question number]_[option number], so the ability to select and apply the recoding using starts_with() is desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly AF, but it does the job. Problem is that setting value labels is not straightforward. Package `labelled` offers functions for it, but these aren't "tidyverse-ready", i.e. they don't work within a mutate, nor do they allow for selecting variables with tidyselect helpers like `starts_with`.

However, `set_value_labels` allos for passing a list where each list element carries the name of the variable you want to apply labels to and then the labels itself are provided as a named vector:

```
x |>  
  mutate(across(starts_with("q0015"), 
                ~dplyr::recode(., `1` = -2, `2` = -1, `3` = 0, `4` = 1, `5` = 2))) |> 
  set_value_labels(.labels = rep(list(c("Very Dissatisfied" = -2,
                                        "Dissatisfied" = -1,
                                        "Neutral" = 0,
                                        "Satisfied" = 1,
                                        "Very Satisfied" = 2)),
                                 x |> 
                                   select(starts_with("q0015")) |> 
                                   ncol()) |> 
                     setNames(nm = x |> 
                                select(starts_with("q0015")) |> 
                                names()))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 25 × 3
   q0015_0001             q0015_0002          q0015_0003            
   <dbl+lbl>              <dbl+lbl>           <dbl+lbl>             
 1  0 [Neutral]            1 [Satisfied]      -1 [Dissatisfied]     
 2  2 [Very Satisfied]     1 [Satisfied]      -1 [Dissatisfied]     
 3 NA                     NA                  NA                    
 4  0 [Neutral]            2 [Very Satisfied]  0 [Neutral]          
 5 -2 [Very Dissatisfied]  0 [Neutral]        -2 [Very Dissatisfied]
 6 -1 [Dissatisfied]       0 [Neutral]        -1 [Dissatisfied]     
 7 NA                     NA                  NA                    
 8 NA                     NA                  NA                    
 9  0 [Neutral]            0 [Neutral]         0 [Neutral]          
10  1 [Satisfied]          1 [Satisfied]       1 [Satisfied]        
# … with 15 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

I was curious and checked with the package developer of the `labelled` package, and an alternative would be to write a small function for recoding and relabeling a single variable and then run this function within `across`:

https://github.com/larmarange/labelled/issues/126

Comment: The alternative (small function to recode/relabel) works well and with a bit of tweaking allows the new values and labels to be passed so the function can be reused for other questions.

Comment: @AWaddington, looking at the github issue, the package dev might release a new package version (soon) in which set_value_labels would work natively and nicely with dplyr::across.